# How can validate Django form field according to specific user group basis, other user should not effect

Tags: django-models, django-forms

How can I validate Django form field according to specific client basis, other client should not effect.
Ex:

```
add_imgpath = models.FileField(upload_to= "addons",verbose_name='image',max_length=300, blank=True)
```

For a specific user group it should be `blank = False`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the client [meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) information from the request object like this:

```
request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

Then use it when you build the form to change the form's `blank` attribute.